# Ajax Button to fetch data without refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I would like to know how a button submit can interact with AJAX to SELECT FROM data as a MySQL query without refreshing the page . I already have a text box interacting with AJAX so that the page does not refresh when the user inputs the text and presses enter but have no idea how to make the button do it my code below shows how im getting the text box to insert data without refreshing

Here is my script for the textbox

```
    <div id="container">
    About me<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Type here and press Enter">
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#name').focus();
        $('#name').keypress(function(event) {
            var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (key == 13) {
                var info = $('#name').val();
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "about_me_action.php",
                    data: {name: info},
                    success: function(status) {
                        $('#result').append(status);
                        $('#name').val('');
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the action

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
echo '<h1>'.$_POST['name'];

include('..\db.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($dbsrvname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$name= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name);



$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE username = '".$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]."'");


   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
       //echo $row['id'];
       $id = $row['id'];
   }

$result=$con ->query=("REPLACE INTO about_user (about_me,number) VALUES ('".$name."','".$id."')");

$insert = $con->query($result);

echo "About Me Updated";
}

?>
```

Now all I need to do is have the below example of a button do something similar but instead of INSERTING just SELECT , how can i change the above script to allow a button to handle the action please?

```
<form 

action="action_mail_view.php"   method="post">

<input type="submit" class="button" name='msubmit'  value="View Mail"/> 

</form>
```

Comment: You can make the button trigger yourself in the javascript code if you want to do it via button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function callServer() {
  $('#mail-button').on('click', function() {
    var info = $('#name').val();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "about_me_action.php",
      data: {
        name: info
      },
      success: function(status) {
        $('#result').append(status);
        $('#name').val('');
      }
    });
  });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#name').focus();
  $('#name').keypress(function(event) {
    var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (key == 13) {
      $('#mail-button').trigger('click');
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="action_mail_view.php" method="post">

  <input type="submit" class="button" id="mail-button" name='msubmit' value="View Mail" />

</form>
```

Comment: Okay but how can I have my query display back results on the page the button is on the action I have has SELECT statements in it that display in a table I just want those results now to show on the same page as the the button ?

Comment: you can append those results to the table in success function of the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't showed us how you tried to make your button work so how can we give you feedback?  Basically you want a similar ajax call that calls `action_mail_view.php` using the `GET` method

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "action_mail_view.php",
    data: {},
    success: function(results) {
        var userinfo = JSON.parse(results);
        //Todo: do what you want with the user's info
    }
});
```

On the PHP side, you should first authenticate the user (not shown here), then `SELECT` her info from the DB and return it

**action_mail_view.php**

```
//Todo: authenticate

//this works with your setup, but it's a bad idea to trust
//a cookie value or anything else coming from the
//browser without verification
$username= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);

//get the user's info from your DB. By using a JOIN, we can execute
//just one query instead of two.
$sql = "SELECT t2.* FROM tbl1 as t1 "
        ."LEFT JOIN about_user as t2 "
        ."ON t1.id = t2.number"
        ."WHERE t1.username = $username";

//Todo: execute query. see what results you get and refine
//      the SELECT clause to get just what you want

if($q = mysqli_query($con,$sql)):
    $userinfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);

    //tell the browser to expect JSON, and return result
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($userinfo);
else:
    //Todo: error handling
endif;
```